# Indentation using the APA6 class

Tags: indentation, apa-style

I'm having some trouble indenting paragraphs using `apa6.cls`. `\indent` does not indent the paragraph, and I have tried `\setlength{\parindent}{5pt}` after `\maketitle`. I am using manuscript mode (`\documentclass[man]{apa}`).

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863). Do you want to indent every paragraph?

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? I get indentation with a test document.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Yes, that is my goal.

Comment: I believe that it is the default behavior of `apa6` to indent every paragraph. Are you talking about the abstract? By APA6 standards, afaik, it is not indented.

Comment: It seems to be the default, except in manuscript mode, which does not indent every paragraph. Anyways, I've temporarily solved this using hspace, but would like to understand why manuscript mode does not indent (or maybe it's just me?)

Comment: @walle1357 In my test the indentation is automatic. Of course, the `man` option is just for preliminary versions of a manuscript: its poor typography makes a document typeset with it not usable for anything other than proof corrections. The parindent measure is 28.9pt, as LaTeX reports.

Comment: An indent of `5pt` is hardly noticeable.  Are you sure that isn't the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a paper in apa6 right now and using `\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}` will work if you put it after `\begin{document}`

I used 20pt instead of 5 though. Maybe 5 was just too small so it wasn't noticeable?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) to format it as code.